# asp.net redirection defect

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net application.the user is clicks on some link which is inside grid item template field. if he is not logged in then he redirects to login page. after log in he is properly coming back to same page;the problem is that **"i have passed the value in querystring to the page where he click on the link and after loggedIn the grid is showing blank because that grid is not getting query string value"** I think you understand my problem.plz share your helpful opinion.

Comment: are you using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(), it will redirect from login page with current url?

Comment: How can he see the grid on a page he is supposed to login to access, if he's not already logged?

Comment: he can see the grid before login but when he clicks on link he needs to login first.after login he get back to that page where he click on link.

Comment: Why does he need to login to see something he can see anyway? Sorry, I just don't get this. Is it because his session timed out?

Comment: after click on link the new grid will open that grid is only visible to logged user.

Comment: And the new grid is on a different page? You need to re-phrase your question because people have no way of knowing that unless you tell them.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/what-is-the-difference-between-server-transfer-and-response-redirect-methods.aspx

It is not a defect, but the desired behavior of Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Store value in session and retrieve it after he gets back successfully from the login page.